# Parenting results in spontaneoudly moving objects (File included)

Tags: modeling, scripting, parent

I have a rocket with multiple stages. All of these stages are rigid bodies, but they're parented to the topmost stage. They're moving up because I switched the gravity upwards to mimic rocket acceleration. I've figured out the cause of the spontaneous movements was when I parented my stages. However, I can't figre out why they move the way they do. Sample of their movement: https://gyazo.com/336e608baa81561455d3afa57a33fdc6 I've scripted their parenting, although I don't think that's the issue either. Here is the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jQAO4dEfP_AxeMbqZyPPCRS7SUqcheOm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you click on one of your child objects and check the rigid body section you will see:

[image]

So change your "needle" shape to "compound parent" and hopefully it works now as you wish.

[image]